# What regulations govern UAV lights in Australia?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, aircraft-external-lights, casa-regulations

I'm a member of a student aviation club at my university, and we're working on a UAV. The club member working on our drone's power supply system has designed a system that uses externally-visible LED lights for displaying system errors to allow for visual inspection of the functionality of our systems, and to allow for us to determine if something goes wrong in flight by looking at it from the ground.

However, I'm uncertain if this would comply with CASA regulations regarding aircraft lights; if it isn't allowed, the current plan is to simply cover the them with a cowling prior to takeoff so that they won't be externally visible. Doing a Google search, I found [this page](https://vfrg.casa.gov.au/operations/night-vfr/aircraft-equipment-for-night-vfr/) on CASA's website detailing requirements for mandating certain navigation lights, but it doesn't say anything about restricting them. It seems fairly likely that red, green, or white lights would be prohibited to prevent confusion with the navigation lights, but would amber lights be allowed?

Comment: Does your question concern only night flight, or daytime flight as well?

Comment: For night time flight you need to comply with https://www.casa.gov.au/drones/reoc/flying-at-night . Lights shouldn't matter during day time, but I cannot substantiate that.

Comment: @bogl Yes, it’d be flying during the day as well.